# How to transfer items from String Lists using 2 button events?

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

As a beginner, I would like to understand the use of events by making a tiles shuffling app. Please help me

I would like a javafx app with two buttons:

- **Button 1 event** `clickToShuffle(MouseEvent mouseEvent)` - Clicking it shuffles a premade string list of 136 items (list1: `String[] allTiles`)
- **Button 2 event** `clickToDeal(MouseEvent mouseEvent)` - Clicking it takes the first 13 items off list1 and transfers them to a new empty list (list2)

**Result details:**

After clicking Button 2, the app must take away the first 13 items from list1. So clicking Button 2 means list1 will then have 123 items inside. list2 becomes a list of those 13 items. It should not be possible to have more than 13 items in list2.

**Problem:**

I am struggling at button 2. I am unable to have the data in "allTiles" list variable available for use in Button 2's "`public void clickToDeal(MouseEvent mouseEvent)`" method

**Question:**

After clicking Button 1, how can I use "allTiles" list (shuffled at this point) and take away 13 items from list1 by clicking button 2 ?

This is the **main** file:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main extends Application {

    String[] allTiles = {};

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/resources/home.fxml"));

        // create tiles Array
        String[] allTiles = new String[] {"1m1","2m1","3m1","4m1","5m1","6m1","7m1","8m1","9m1","1m2","2m2","3m2","4m2","5m2","6m2","7m2","8m2","9m2","1m3","2m3","3m3","4m3","5m3","6m3","7m3","8m3","9m3","1m4","2m4","3m4","4m4","5m4","6m4","7m4","8m4","9m4","1s1","2s1","3s1","4s1","5s1","6s1","7s1","8s1","9s1","1s2","2s2","3s2","4s2","5s2","6s2","7s2","8s2","9s2","1s3","2s3","3s3","4s3","5s3","6s3","7s3","8s3","9s3","1s4","2s4","3s4","4s4","5s4","6s4","7s4","8s4","9s4","1p1","2p1","3p1","4p1","5p1","6p1","7p1","8p1","9p1","1p2","2p2","3p2","4p2","5p2","6p2","7p2","8p2","9p2","1p3","2p3","3p3","4p3","5p3","6p3","7p3","8p3","9p3","1p4","2p4","3p4","4p4","5p4","6p4","7p4","8p4","9p4","n1","n2","n3","n4","e1","e2","e3","e4","w1","w2","w3","w4","s1","s2","s3","s4","dr1","dr2","dr3","dr4","dg1","dg2","dg3","dg4","dw1","dw2","dw3","dw4"};
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(allTiles));



        primaryStage.setWidth(1280);
        primaryStage.setHeight(720);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 275));
        primaryStage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

This is the **controller** file:

```
package controller;

import com.sun.tools.javac.Main;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

public class Controller extends Main {
    public void clickToShuffle(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {

        // create tiles Array
        String[] allTiles = new String[] {"1m1","2m1","3m1","4m1","5m1","6m1","7m1","8m1","9m1","1m2","2m2","3m2","4m2","5m2","6m2","7m2","8m2","9m2","1m3","2m3","3m3","4m3","5m3","6m3","7m3","8m3","9m3","1m4","2m4","3m4","4m4","5m4","6m4","7m4","8m4","9m4","1s1","2s1","3s1","4s1","5s1","6s1","7s1","8s1","9s1","1s2","2s2","3s2","4s2","5s2","6s2","7s2","8s2","9s2","1s3","2s3","3s3","4s3","5s3","6s3","7s3","8s3","9s3","1s4","2s4","3s4","4s4","5s4","6s4","7s4","8s4","9s4","1p1","2p1","3p1","4p1","5p1","6p1","7p1","8p1","9p1","1p2","2p2","3p2","4p2","5p2","6p2","7p2","8p2","9p2","1p3","2p3","3p3","4p3","5p3","6p3","7p3","8p3","9p3","1p4","2p4","3p4","4p4","5p4","6p4","7p4","8p4","9p4","n1","n2","n3","n4","e1","e2","e3","e4","w1","w2","w3","w4","s1","s2","s3","s4","dr1","dr2","dr3","dr4","dg1","dg2","dg3","dg4","dw1","dw2","dw3","dw4"};
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(allTiles));

        // Converting tiles Array to List String
        List<String> list = Arrays.asList(allTiles);
        System.out.println(list);
        System.out.println(allTiles.length);
        System.out.println(list.size());

        // shuffle

        for (int i = 0; i < allTiles.length; i++) {
            int index = (int)(Math.random()*allTiles.length);
            String shuffleTmp = allTiles[i];
            allTiles[i] = allTiles[index];
            allTiles[index] = shuffleTmp;
        }




    }
```

Then this is the **fxml** file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.SplitPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.Image?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.ImageView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.RowConstraints?>

<BorderPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="720.0" prefWidth="1280.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="controller.Controller">
   <bottom>
      <HBox prefHeight="161.0" prefWidth="1280.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
         <children>
            <Button fx:id="btn_00" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="50.0" minWidth="71.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="86.0" prefWidth="81.0" translateX="90.0" translateY="5.0">
               <graphic>
                  <ImageView fx:id="handTile_00" fitHeight="170.0" fitWidth="80.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
                     <image>
                        <Image url="@Black/Back.png" />
                     </image>
                  </ImageView>
               </graphic>
            </Button>
            <Button fx:id="btn_01" layoutX="10.0" layoutY="10.0" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="50.0" minWidth="71.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="86.0" prefWidth="79.0" translateX="90.0" translateY="5.0">
               <graphic>
                  <ImageView fx:id="handTile_01" fitHeight="170.0" fitWidth="80.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
                     <image>
                        <Image url="@Black/Back.png" />
                     </image>
                  </ImageView>
               </graphic>
            </Button>
            <Button fx:id="btn_02" layoutX="81.0" layoutY="10.0" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="50.0" minWidth="71.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="89.0" prefWidth="80.0" translateX="90.0" translateY="5.0">
               <graphic>
                  <ImageView fx:id="handTile_02" fitHeight="170.0" fitWidth="80.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
                     <image>
                        <Image url="@Black/Back.png" />
                     </image>
                  </ImageView>
               </graphic>
            </Button>
            <Button fx:id="btn_03" layoutX="170.0" layoutY="10.0" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="50.0" minWidth="71.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="89.0" prefWidth="80.0" translateX="90.0" translateY="5.0">
               <graphic>
                  <ImageView fx:id="handTile_03" fitHeight="170.0" fitWidth="80.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
                     <image>
                        <Image url="@Black/Back.png" />
                     </image>
                  </ImageView>
               </graphic>
            </Button>
            <Button fx:id="btn_04" layoutX="250.0" layoutY="10.0" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="50.0" minWidth="71.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="89.0" prefWidth="80.0" translateX="90.0" translateY="5.0">
               <graphic>
                  <ImageView fx:id="handTile_04" fitHeight="170.0" fitWidth="80.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
                     <image>
                        <Image url="@Black/Back.png" />
                     </image>
                  </ImageView>
               </graphic>
            </Button>
            <Button fx:id="btn_05" layoutX="330.0" layoutY="10.0" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="50.0" minWidth="71.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="89.0" prefWidth="80.0" translateX="90.0" translateY="5.0">
               <graphic>
                  <ImageView fx:id="handTile_05" fitHeight="170.0" fitWidth="80.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
                     <image>
                        <Image url="@Black/Back.png" />
                     </image>
                  </ImageView>
               </graphic>
            </Button>
            <Button fx:id="btn_06" layoutX="410.0" layoutY="10.0" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="50.0" minWidth="71.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="89.0" prefWidth="80.0" translateX="90.0" translateY="5.0">
               <graphic>
                  <ImageView fx:id="handTile_06" fitHeight="170.0" fitWidth="80.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
                     <image>
                        <Image url="@Black/Back.png" />
                     </image>
                  </ImageView>
               </graphic>
            </Button>
            <Button fx:id="btn_07" layoutX="490.0" layoutY="10.0" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="50.0" minWidth="71.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="89.0" prefWidth="80.0" translateX="90.0" translateY="5.0">
               <graphic>
                  <ImageView fx:id="handTile_07" fitHeight="170.0" fitWidth="80.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
                     <image>
                        <Image url="@Black/Back.png" />
                     </image>
                  </ImageView>
               </graphic>
            </Button>
            <Button fx:id="btn_08" layoutX="570.0" layoutY="10.0" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="50.0" minWidth="71.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="89.0" prefWidth="80.0" translateX="90.0" translateY="5.0">
               <graphic>
                  <ImageView fx:id="handTile_08" fitHeight="170.0" fitWidth="80.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
                     <image>
                        <Image url="@Black/Back.png" />
                     </image>
                  </ImageView>
               </graphic>
            </Button>
            <Button fx:id="btn_09" layoutX="650.0" layoutY="10.0" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="50.0" minWidth="71.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="89.0" prefWidth="80.0" translateX="90.0" translateY="5.0">
               <graphic>
                  <ImageView fx:id="handTile_09" fitHeight="170.0" fitWidth="80.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
                     <image>
                        <Image url="@Black/Back.png" />
                     </image>
                  </ImageView>
               </graphic>
            </Button>
            <Button fx:id="btn_10" layoutX="570.0" layoutY="10.0" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="50.0" minWidth="71.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="89.0" prefWidth="80.0" translateX="90.0" translateY="5.0">
               <graphic>
                  <ImageView fx:id="handTile_10" fitHeight="170.0" fitWidth="80.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
                     <image>
                        <Image url="@Black/Back.png" />
                     </image>
                  </ImageView>
               </graphic>
            </Button>
            <Button fx:id="btn_11" layoutX="650.0" layoutY="10.0" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="50.0" minWidth="71.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="89.0" prefWidth="80.0" translateX="90.0" translateY="5.0">
               <graphic>
                  <ImageView fx:id="handTile_11" fitHeight="170.0" fitWidth="80.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
                     <image>
                        <Image url="@Black/Back.png" />
                     </image>
                  </ImageView>
               </graphic>
            </Button>
            <Button fx:id="btn_12" layoutX="730.0" layoutY="10.0" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="50.0" minWidth="71.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="89.0" prefWidth="80.0" translateX="90.0" translateY="5.0">
               <graphic>
                  <ImageView fx:id="handTile_12" fitHeight="170.0" fitWidth="80.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
                     <image>
                        <Image url="@Black/Back.png" />
                     </image>
                  </ImageView>
               </graphic>
            </Button>
         </children>
      </HBox>
   </bottom>
   <top>
      <SplitPane dividerPositions="0.5" orientation="VERTICAL" prefHeight="319.0" prefWidth="1280.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
        <items>
          <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="160.0" />
          <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="135.0" prefWidth="1285.0">
               <children>
                  <GridPane prefHeight="126.0" prefWidth="1168.0">
                    <columnConstraints>
                      <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="-Infinity" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="96.0" />
                      <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="-Infinity" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="96.0" />
                        <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="-Infinity" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="96.0" />
                        <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="-Infinity" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="96.0" />
                        <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="-Infinity" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="96.0" />
                        <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="-Infinity" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="96.0" />
                        <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="-Infinity" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="96.0" />
                        <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="-Infinity" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="96.0" />
                        <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="-Infinity" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="96.0" />
                        <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="-Infinity" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="96.0" />
                        <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="-Infinity" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="96.0" />
                        <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="-Infinity" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="96.0" />
                        <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="-Infinity" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="96.0" />
                    </columnConstraints>
                    <rowConstraints>
                      <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                    </rowConstraints>
                  </GridPane>
               </children>
            </AnchorPane>
        </items>
      </SplitPane>
   </top>
   <center>
      <BorderPane prefHeight="157.0" prefWidth="1280.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
         <bottom>
            <HBox fx:id="nextTile_hbox" prefHeight="118.0" prefWidth="1280.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
               <children>
                  <ImageView fx:id="nextTile_00" fitHeight="170.0" fitWidth="80.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" rotate="90.0" translateX="170.0" translateY="18.0">
                     <image>
                        <Image url="@Black/Back.png" />
                     </image>
                  </ImageView>
               </children>
            </HBox>
         </bottom>
         <left>
            <Button fx:id="shuffle_btn" mnemonicParsing="false" onMouseClicked="#clickToShuffle" prefHeight="54.0" prefWidth="120.0" text="Shuffle" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER" />
         </left>
         <top>
            <Button fx:id="deal_btn" mnemonicParsing="false" onMouseClicked="#clickToDeal" prefHeight="53.0" prefWidth="120.0" text="Deal" BorderPane.alignment="TOP_LEFT" />
         </top>
      </BorderPane>
   </center>
</BorderPane>
```

Comment: You have declared `allTiles` in three places. First as member of class `Main`. Second as local variable in method `start()` of class `Main` and third as local variable in method `clickToShuffle()` in class `Controller`. Just leave the member declaration and remove the `String[]` from the other declarations.

Comment: If I remove the String[] as you suggested, there is an error in Controller.java "Cannot resolve symbol 'allTiles". Fix suggested is "Create local variable "allTiles". Which goes back to my original problem unfortunately :(

Comment: Use `Collections.shuffle(yourList);` to shuffle your list.

Comment: There should be no `String[] allTiles` in the Main class. Give `List<String> list;` greater scope in the Controller. In `clickToShuffle` do `list = Arrays.asList(allTiles);`. Then use `Collections.shuffle(list);`.

Comment: Thank you very much the answers helped me fix it !